# How can I increase speed of SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

As a Image that I sent , [image]

For getting count of comment can I add one filed in table of Module or not , my mean is for big record like 100 million comments or big project, which one is **better/faster** adding one filed to module and after each inserting comment update it or have a relationship

For getting **count of comment** , I must to choose which one :

```
select Module.Id,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr1
        FROM dbo.CommentTable 
        WHERE (CommentTable.MuoduleId= Module.userid)) AS commentCount
from Model
```

or

```
select Module.Id, Module.CountComment
```

Comment: Compute it on the fly. With a proper index, it should be fast to query.

Comment: what's with the jquery tag man??

Comment: @madalinivascu Come on now! Everyone knows it's doable in jquery.

Comment: @FelixPamittan ya in "j query", "java script" :)))

Comment: so what's the answer , this is query of SQL :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you compute it on the fly instead of saving the count in the table itself. To get the count of comments of each `Module`:

```
SELECT
    m.id,
    CommentCount = COUNT(c.ModuleId)
FROM Module m
LEFT JOIN CommentTable c
    ON c.ModuleId = m.Id
GROUP BY m.id
```

This will be faster if you have an index on `CommentTable(ModuleId)`:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCI_CommentTable_ModuleId ON CommentTable(ModuleId)
```

Comment: so are you saying using index on second table makes the query faster with relationship

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying.